# Using the execute shell command in Jenkins to run git commands on a Windows machine

Tags: windows, git, shell, jenkins, cygwin

I need to run a bash script that periodically deletes old git branches. I am having trouble finding a way to connect to the git repo via the execute shell option.

Currently I am using cygwin in order to run git commands. Here is what I have in execute shell:

```
#!c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login
git ls-remote git@10.1.1.126:/external-web/collette-com.git
```

This command is throwing the following error.

```
[Delete Branches] $ c:\cygwin64\bin\bash --login 

C:\Users\tbraga\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson5750784484659728632.sh
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

I have tried running this command in the command line and am prompted for a password. Could this be the issue?

I have the git plugin configured within Jenkins and the connection works perfectly when using Source Code Management Git.

Any suggestions on how to make this connections work in the execute shell field would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would `git ls-remote git@10.1.1.126:/external-web/collette-com.git` works from a `C:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.7.0-64-bit\git-bash.exe` session? Normally, you don't need Cygwin at all.

Comment: When I run the command from git bash I am prompted for a password

Comment: It just means your $HOME/.ssh does not include the private/public `id_rsa/id_rsa.pub` to open an ssh session on 10.1.1.126.

Comment: Users have experienced attempted Git operations that never make any progress and eventually time out when targeting password-protected https repository locations. : https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34082

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by passing my credentials to my execute shell script through the Credentials Binding Plugin in Jenkins

Comment: @swiss196 It was just a plugin module "Credentials Binding Plugin" all I had to do was enter my username and password

Answer (score 0):

It's simple enough to create an SSH key associated with your user.

Try here : https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/creating-ssh-keys-776639788.html

Put keys under %userprofile%/.ssh and try running it again.

You can also use the same credentials used in your Jenkins configuration

Comment: I was able to configure the SSH keys so that I can pull remotely from the repository using git bash and the command line. However, it is still not able to access the repo in Jenkins. I am not the user that is configured in Jenkins. Is it enough to move my .ssh file to this users folders or does this user have to log in and run the commands?

Answer (score 0):

I use SSH keys for auth to Github and had this same issue. My Jenkins configuration has EC2 slaves, so the default SSH key on the machine wasn't correct for Github.

I fixed it with the [SSH Agent Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SSH+Agent+Plugin). In the job, enable the "SSH Agent" setting and choose the stored SSH key for Github authentication. It should be the same one selected for the Git-SCM configuration used to clone the repo.